# ¿cómo ordenar usando fetchall?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

estoy usando este código para poder buscar los datos de mi BD pero necesito ordenarlos colocando un campo "efemerides" como primero o superior de todos.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM events ";
$events = $req->fetchAll();
```

el campo a usar es efemerides. 
lo estoy intentando usando el ORDER BY en la consulta pero no me muestra nada mi página.

Comment: Cual es la consulta que haces con el ORDER BY?

Comment: todos las tablas de mi base de datos event

Comment: necesito es que $events sea ordenado @alex55132

Comment: Vale, enseñeme esa consulta ORDER BY que dice que no le muestra nada

Comment: $sql = "SELECT title, color FROM events ORDER BY color";

Comment: Puede enseñar el código CREATE de la tabla y agregarla a la pregunta para poder reproducir su problema?

Comment: ¿Ese es todo el código?  ¿La tabla `events` tiene una columna llamada `title` y otra llamada `color`?